# GitLab API Token is not visibile in Jenkins Credentials

Tags: android, jenkins, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

After getting the private token from GitLab and trying to create credentials in Jenkins. The newly created credential is not visible in the dropdown.

Creating the credential
[image]

No Credentials are visible when opening the dropdown
[image]

I am on Jenkins ver. 2.73.3 and GitLab Plugin 1.5.1